# Is it okay to nest nginx reverse proxies

Tags: performance, nginx, reverse-proxy, proxypass

Is it wise to `proxy_pass` back to nginx multiple times, for example from SSL to non-SSL to another server? I want to maintain configuration organization and seprate the HTTPS from HTTP.

Is there another means of aliasing to a specific `server_name`? Or are there better ways to do this (UNIX sockets instead?)? Or is the performance impact negligable (for a home server)?

Answer (score 2):

For a home server it is completely fine.

For a high performance server probably it would be more efficient to keep the processing loop's number on the minimum.